# Why is my database so large?

Tags: sql-server, diskspace

Of course you can't answer that question. But I hope someone can point me to a way/tool to analyse which parts of my database are allocating so much space.

So, what tools do you use to check where your SQL-Server databases are using all that expensive disk space?

Comment: I would start with including as much information as possible, like for example software used, db type etc. :)

Comment: I can answer that question. There are a lot of data in it!!! ;)

Comment: @Fuji the question is tagged sql-server

Comment: Ah @ChrisShain for me that is a generic term for SQL server (like MySQL, MSSQL etc) but clicking on it I realized that it does specify MSSQL. :)

Comment: -1 Your question does not indicate any research effort.

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty easily googled- here's a script for finding the size of each table: http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2007/07/27/determing-sql-server-table-size.aspx